# How to create a sublist of elements with a congruence relation

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional

I generated a list made up of lists of four elements such as:

```
n = {{49, 9, 9, 5}, {57, 13, 9, 5}, {81, 21, 13, 5}, {95, 19, 19, 7},...}
```

I would like to create a sublist that only contains lists whose elements are all congruent to 1 mod 4. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

You can write a very explicit and readable code by using `Select` and `AllTrue`

```
n = {{49, 9, 9, 5}, {57, 13, 9, 5}, {81, 21, 13, 5}, {95, 19,
     19, 7}};

Select[n, AllTrue[Mod[#, 4] == 1 &]]

(* {{49, 9, 9, 5}, {57, 13, 9, 5}, {81, 21, 13, 5}} *)
```

but in my experience, casting the problem in term of `Pick` gives often the fastest code.

```
n = RandomInteger[100, {10^5, 4}];

sub1 = Select[n, AllTrue[Mod[#, 4] == 1 &]]; // RepeatedTiming
sub2 = DeleteCases[Pick[n, Mod[n, 4], {1, 1, 1, 1}], {}]; // RepeatedTiming

(* {0.15, Null} *)

(* {0.0700, Null} *)

sub1 === sub2

(*  True *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Indeed, `Pick` is very fast. A bit faster is using some integer vector arithmetic to create a scalar condition for picking:

```
n = RandomInteger[100, {10^2, 5}];
sub1 = Select[n, AllTrue[Mod[#, 4] == 1 &]]; // RepeatedTiming // First
sub2 = DeleteCases[Pick[n, Mod[n, 4], {1, 1, 1, 1}], {}]; // RepeatedTiming // First

sub3 = Pick[n, Mod[n - 1, 4].ConstantArray[1, 4], 0]; // RepeatedTiming // First
sub1 == sub2 == sub3
```

> 0.132
>
> 0.045
>
> 0.0030
>
> True

Comment: True. If you have time, it's always better to simplify the pattern to a simple expression with no parts like `True`/`False` or `1`/`0`.

Comment: Note also that `Pick[n, Mod[n, 4], {1, 1, 1, 1}]` creates an unpacked array and that arrays with `True` and `False` cannot be packed. (Btw., I consider this a shortcoming of Mathematica)

Comment: This is because there is no native bit data type. The best you can get is a byte image or a `ByteArray` but there's not much support for those yet outside their respective domain.

Comment: That's what I meant...

Answer (score 3):

Another way using pattern matching and replacement (probably slower than the other implementations):

```
n = {{49, 9, 9, 5}, {57, 13, 9, 5}, {81, 21, 13, 5}, {95, 19, 19, 7}};
n /. list_List?(! And @@ Thread[Mod[#, 4] == 1] &) -> Sequence[]
(*{{49, 9, 9, 5}, {57, 13, 9, 5}, {81, 21, 13, 5}}*)
```

**Edit:**

One could also use `Nothing` instead of `Sequence[]` to represent an element that will automatically be removed.